# Why is DDMS no longer opening?

Tags: java, eclipse, android-studio, ddms

Android DDMS was working the other day, but today (after 1.1 update) it always pops up an error message, that says to check the log file. The end of the log file is:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-02-23 20:36:49.944
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.URIUtil.toURI(URIUtil.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadMostRecentModel(ResourceHandler.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorApplication.start(MonitorApplication.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

The SDK seems up-to-date yet no ddms, Ubuntu 14.04. Is this a known bug or is there extra setup required for this update??

Answer (score 8):

Check your processes, you likely have another instance of the `monitor` or `ddms` tool running. Pretty lame of Google not to expect that might happen and give a nice message about it.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I tried opening DDMS the other way

1. Open terminal
2. Then go to your sdk location
3. then inside tools.
4. run ./ddms

Doing this will open ddms.